# Web link URI to open specific whatsapp contact in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, hyperlink, uri, whatsapp

I'm trying to open Whatsapp application through a web link. I need to open a specific conversation with specifi phone number. 
I've found some code that works in android but not iOS:

```
<a href="intent://send/+1234567890#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
```

that "+1234567890" is the phone number.
I need the same code working in iOS.
Maybe these links help:

[I'm an iPhone developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp into my app?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

[I'm an Android developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp with my app?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

Comment: do you found any solutions for this?

Comment: anyone found solution for this?